# How to implement MouseUp event on radgrid row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, radgrid

I am working on a scenario of dragging the radtreeview node onto Radgrid row ,where I need to get the row id value as soon as I leave the node upon the grid row.

I have seen examples but they are giving the row cell value (not comple row values) when I drop the node on it

So I want to write a MouseUp event similar to MouseOver.

I want to know how to implement **MouseUp/MouseDown** events on the radgrid row.

Thank you
Ramesh.T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jquery,

```
function droppedOnGrid(args)
{
    var target = args.get_htmlElement();

    // To get the row of cell
    var row = $(target).parent()
    // Find the value in the cell which you want
    var id = row.children()[index].val();
    ......
```

hope that helps